# How to add marker on google map with two locations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, location, google-maps-markers

I would like to add markers on google map with two locations, that are clickable. When I click on the button it should change the map marker with the location.

```
 <script>
    var map;
    function initialize()
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.302516, 16.414546), //Setting Initial Position
            zoom: 14,

        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newLocation(),
            map: map,
            title: 'AGM-CORP',
            icon: 'img/agm-marker.png'
        });
    }

    function newLocation(newLat, newLng)
    {
        map.setCenter({
            lat: newLat,
            lng: newLng
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#1").on('click', function ()
        {
            newLocation(52.302516, 16.414546);
        });

        $("#2").on('click', function ()
        {
            newLocation(51.706478, 15.274753);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
    <h3>Zobacz lokalizację:</h3>
    <button id="1" style="padding:10px; cursor:pointer;">Siedziba Firmy</button>
    <button id="2" style="padding:10px;cursor:pointer;">Kopalnia Kruszyw</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: Yup, that's exactly how you do it. You create an array of your locations and their lat/lng and info window information. This is a great site for converting addresses to lat and lng https://www.latlong.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var map = null
var marker = null;
var myLatLng = {
  lat: 52.302516,
  lng: 16.414546
};

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng.lat, myLatLng.lng),
    zoom: 14,
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

function updateMap(lat, lng) {;
  myLatLng.lat = lat;
  myLatLng.lng = lng
  map.setCenter(myLatLng);
  marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").on('click', function() {
    updateMap(52.302516, 16.414546);
  });

  $("#2").on('click', function() {
    updateMap(51.706478, 15.274753);
  });
});
```

I am initing the map with new marker.
[Working jffiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/gp230mx9/4/)

Comment: I have copied your code but it is strange because the map doesn't show on my page...

Comment: The map shows only when I click the button. Not while I refresh the page on load

Comment: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

Comment: Why you should reInit the map for every time you click the button ?. Its inefficient

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: @VigneshRaja I have updated accordingly.. No need to setMap to null also.

Comment: Is that really working ? The marker is not aligned to center

Comment: small bug, variable was initialized twice.. its working.. try again

Answer (score 0):

this function will only switch the location of the view:

```
map.setCenter({
   lat: newLat,
   lng: newLng
});
```

use this instead:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
```

secondly to you need to add event listner to the marker object for it to work properly:

```
// create markers on the map
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ ... })
marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ ... })
marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({ ... })

// add event listener
marker1.addListener('click', function() { ... })
marker2.addListener('click', function() { ... })
```

further check out the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) they are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Have a global variable that holds the `marker`. Whenever the location is changed, set the marker in the position of `Lat` and `Lng` using the `setPosition` method and use `setCenter` method to show the marker in the center. No need to init the map every time.

```
var map,marker;
function initialize()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.302516, 16.414546), //Setting Initial Position
        zoom: 6,
    });
    setLocation(52.302516,16.414546);
}

function setLocation(newLat, newLng)
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);
    if(marker) //Remove the marker, if already set
    {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'AGM-CORP'
    });
    map.setCenter(latlng);

}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#1").on('click', function ()
    {
        setLocation(13.070814558816117, 80.2656996835234);
    });

    $("#2").on('click', function ()
    {
        setLocation(59.4739316352335,-110.89646088128342);
    });
});
```